# Create SQLite Table With Variable

Tags: python, sqlite

I want to create three tables `fremdgehen.com`, `molligundwillig.de` and `reifer6.de`.

But I am not able to transfer each element to `CREATE TABLE`. Why?

```
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect('emails.db')
cur = con.cursor()

pages = ['fremdgehen.com', 'molligundwillig.de', 'reifer6.de']

for i in pages:
    try:
        sql_command = f'''
        CREATE TABLE {i} (
            email INTEGER,
            password VARCHAR,
            PRIMARY KEY (id));
        cur.executescript(sql_command)
        con.commit()
        '''
    except:
        pass

con.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the table names contain a `.` character, you have to escape the names.

```
        sql_command = f'''
        CREATE TABLE `{i}` (
            email INTEGER,
            password VARCHAR,
            PRIMARY KEY (id));
        cur.executescript(sql_command)
        con.commit()
        '''
```

Note that having `.` in table and column names is inconvenient, because `.` is the separator between database, table, and column names. So you'll have to escape the table name in all your queries. Consider removing the `.` before using it as a table name to simplify this.

Comment: Is it inconvenient  to use `_` instead of `.`?

Comment: `_` is a common character. So you could use `{i.replace('.', '_')}` in the f-string.